# How to use Refresh with a wx.ColourDialog in wxpython?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

i am trying to Refresh() a panel which uses the wx.ColourDialog. Once I refresh the panel once, it is unable to refresh again. Try the following to see the problem in action.

By clicking the button, it will ask you what color you would like to change the rectangle to. Once you press OK, it should change the rectangles color. It will not work it will not change the rectangle.

```
import wx 
xcolor_of_font_dia=(0,0,0)
class MyFrame(wx.Frame): 
    """a frame with a panel"""
    def __init__(self, parent=None, id=wx.ID_ANY, title=None):
        global xcolor_of_font_dia
        global dc
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, title) 
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, size=(350, 200)) 
        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.on_paint)
        self.button2 = wx.Button(self.panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label='Button2',pos=(8, 38), size=(175, 28))
        self.button2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onColorDlg)
        self.Fit() 
    def onColorDlg(self, event):
        global xcolor_of_font_dia
        global dc
        """
        This is mostly from the wxPython Demo!
        """
        dlg = wx.ColourDialog(self)

        # Ensure the full colour dialog is displayed, 
        # not the abbreviated version.
        dlg.GetColourData().SetChooseFull(True)

        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            data = dlg.GetColourData()
            print 'You selected: %s\n' % str(data.GetColour().Get())
            xcolor_of_font_dia='#%02x%02x%02x' % data.GetColour().Get()
        dlg.Destroy()
        self.panel.Refresh()
    def on_paint(self, event):
        global xcolor_of_font_dia
        global dc
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self.panel)
        dc.SetPen(wx.Pen(xcolor_of_font_dia, 1))
        rect = wx.Rect(50, 50, 100, 100) 
        dc.DrawRoundedRectangleRect(rect, 8)


# test it ...
app = wx.PySimpleApp() 
frame1 = MyFrame(title='rounded-rectangle & circle') 
frame1.Center() 
frame1.Show() 
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Works For Me(TM). Had to add a `dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush(xcolor_of_font_dia))` to make it more evident, thought.

Comment: Did you try, changing the colour twice?

Comment: I changed the color a few times in a row. The rectangle changes to the right one every time.

Comment: @RicardoCárdenes Did it worked? In my case I got exactly the same behavior described by the OP. First time worked, not anymore. This is win 7 64-bit, wxpython 2.8.12.1 in ActivePython 2.6.7

Comment: @joaquin: yeah, it did work. Same wxPython version, but Linux and Python 2.7.2. No changes on the code (except for filling the rectangle). As wx uses a native widget library for each platform, it could be that the problem shows only on Windows.

Comment: @RicardoCárdenes Here if you make dc global, it looks like the frame enters in a very fast, never ending loop repainting the rectangle. I see the border like trembling (Instead of filling the rectangle I made the border thicker with wx.Pen). The button still works but the colour dialog object, despite it is created, does not show anymore. Strange...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned your code a bit. Basically your globals were producing some problems as you were creating (and deleting) different dc instances after every size event.
You should not use globals if it is not strictly necessary (rarely is).

This works:

```
import wx 


class MyFrame(wx.Frame): 
    """a frame with a panel"""
    def __init__(self, parent=None, id=wx.ID_ANY, title=None):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, title) 
        self.xcolor = (0, 0, 0)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, size=(350, 200)) 
        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.on_paint)
        self.button2 = wx.Button(self.panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label='Button2',
                                             pos=(8, 38), size=(175, 28))
        self.button2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onColorDlg)

        self.Fit() 

    def onColorDlg(self, event):
        """
        This is mostly from the wxPython Demo!
        """
        dlg = wx.ColourDialog(None)
        dlg.GetColourData().SetChooseFull(True)

        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            data = dlg.GetColourData()
            self.xcolor = data.GetColour().Get()
            print 'You selected: %s\n' % str(self.xcolor)

        dlg.Destroy()
        self.panel.Refresh()

    def on_paint(self, event):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self.panel)
        dc.SetPen(wx.Pen(self.xcolor, 2))
        rect = wx.Rect(50, 50, 100, 100) 
        dc.DrawRoundedRectangleRect(rect, 8)


# test it ...
app = wx.PySimpleApp() 
frame1 = MyFrame(title='rounded-rectangle & circle') 
frame1.Center() 
frame1.Show() 
app.MainLoop()
```